# Creating new project in Eclipse then adding it to a Mercurial repo

Tags: java, mercurial, dvcs, mercurialeclipse

I have access to an existing Mercurial repo located at `merc.myorg.com/hghome`. I have been asked to whip up a simple Java tool and commit it to the repo under `hghome/myapp`. I have never used Mercurial before, and would like to accomplish the following:

- Write the code in Eclipse
- Use the [`MercurialEclipse`](https://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/main/wiki/Home) plugin to get the sourcecode (`myapp`) up under `hghome`

My first thought was to write all the code in an Eclipse project, and then try to connect to `hghome` somehow and push/copy all the code up to the server at the desired location. But then I figured that I probably can't push code to a repo/sub-repo (`hghome/myapp`) that doesn't exist yet. So it feels like a chicken-and-the-egg sort of problem.

Let's pretend that `myapp` is a simple (Eclipse) Java project with the following directory structure:

```
myapp/
    src/main/java/ (Source Folder)
        com.myorg.myapp (Package)
            MyApp.java
    build.xml
```

I have already installed Mercurial and the MercurialEclipse plugin. What are the exact steps I need to take to accomplish writing this, and getting it checked into a new repo at `hghome/myapp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to have an Eclipse project in a sub directory of a larger repository. I think there is no reason for you to use "subrepositores", instead you can use the single monolithic repository.

1. Using MercurialEclipse or another tool clone merc.myorg.com/hghome
2. Create the sub directory myapp and in it create an file with the name ".project"
3. In ".project" add appropriate Eclipse project configuration. For example `<projectDescription><name>myapp</name>[...]</projectDescription>`.
4. Commit ".project" and push it to the central server.
5. Using MercurialEclipse clone merc.myorg.com/hghome again. This time on the last page it will allow you to import "myapp" as a project. It will show up in your workspace as an empty project.